# Vectorize over the rows of an array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have an array `X` and I want to apply a function `f` to all the rows of `X`:

```
# silly example
X = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]], 'i')

def f(row): return sum(row)

y = numpy.vectorize(f, 'i')(rows(X))
```

Now, `y` should be `array([15,30], 'i')`. Which method or slicing magic will implement `rows` in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NumPy implements the concept of "action over a particular axis".  The general function is [`numpy.apply_along_axis()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
>>> numpy.apply_along_axis(sum, 1, X)
array([15, 30])
```

(where `sum` can of course be replaced by anything).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really want the sum, that's just part of the "silly example" bit.

Comment: I think the "#silly example" line means that the OP is looking for a general solution

Comment: @larsmans and JoshAdel: yeah, I was adding the general case while you were writing the comments. :)

Comment: The thing that takes the place of `sum`, does it have to return a scalar?

Comment: @David: the function can return a list, for instance; the result is in this case a full NumPy array with the correct shape.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be something provided by numpy? Because I just see a list comprehension

```
[action_to_apply(row) for row in X]
```

Comment: This is quite similar to what I have now. I was hoping to push the loop down to the C level.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another shot at it, which takes into account the type and size of the result:

```
numpy.fromiter((your_func(row) for row in X), dtype=bool, count=len(X))
```

Even though the loop is not a C loop, setting the type and size of the result might help speed things up.